# Firebase Flutter ios App stuck on "Run your app to verify installation" step

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried to integrate my Flutter App with Firebase. It worked fine with android app, but it won't work with the ios app. I follow every steps on Flutter Doc, and it still won't work.

Can someone tell me what might went wrong?

[The image of Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrguH.png)

Comment: You should follow [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) about integrating Firebase in a Flutter app

Comment: I followed that article, but it won’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!

I change the position of PlugIns in pubspec.yaml File, the I run Package Get.
Finally, it worked!

Comment: How you solved this issue. I am also facing the same issue. It's working fine in Android. But not working on iOS devices

Comment: As a clarification to the answer - I had the same problem and moved the `cloud_firestore` dependency under the flutter one to fix it. Also deleted the app from the simulator before installing it again.